# "unshare --mount" inside a jenkins chroot environment

Tags: linux, mount, unshare

In some of my build scripts I've been using mount namespaces as a mechanism to safely mount without ever leaving these mounts behind when the script terminates.  [Unshared mount points are implicitly unmounted when the last process in that namespace exits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212172/what-happens-if-the-last-process-in-a-namespace-exits).

My scripts usually include a stansa such as this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
self_ns=$(ls -lh /proc/self/ns/mnt)
init_ns=$(ls -lh /proc/$PPID/ns/mnt)
if [ "${self_ns#*mnt:}" = "${init_ns#*mnt:}" ] ; then
    unshare --mount $0 "$@"
    exit $?
fi
```

While this has worked fine for me for some time I've recently run into a problem on a jenkins build server.

I believe the issue there is that the build script itself is being executed inside a [jenkins chroot environment](https://github.com/rmohr/chroot-plugin).  So when the script executes `unshare --mount ...`, it fails with the error:

```
unshare: cannot change root filesystem propagation: Invalid argument
```

Unfortunately I really don't understand this restriction or how to get round it.  When I try a chroot on the command line I can't replicate this error.  I don't know what the jenkins plugin has done to cause this.

The most important thing is that these mount points are removed on exit *every time without fail*.

Comment: I note it succeeds in entering a new mount namespace. But then it tries to do the equivalent of `mount --make-rprivate /`. Which is something you want. Or at least you want `mount --make-rslave /`. The exact thing `unshare` does here is controlled by the `--propagation` option.

Comment: I looked at the list of EINVAL errors in `man 2 mount`, but I don't think any of those explain your problem.

Comment: @sourcejedi its odd under jenkings chroot, the `unshare` itself fails.  But I haven't been able to construct a chroot environment that does the same from the command line.

Comment: I get the same error if I chroot to an lxc's rootfs directory installation and `unshare --mount bash`. If I first bind mount (--private) this directory elsewhere and then do the chroot there, `unshare --mount` then works. I don't know what this means, but I hope this can help find the cause or a workaround (adding a bind mount in the pipeline).

Comment: @A.B wow. For some reason I can `mount --bind --make-private / /mnt`  Then
`chroot /mnt unshare --mount bash -c 'echo hello'` but not `unshare --mount bash -c 'echo hello'`.  Okay that's a viable work around, whatever the cause was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on A.B's comment I have found a workaround:

A.B wrote:

> I get the same error if I chroot to an lxc's rootfs directory installation and `unshare --mount bash`. If I first bind mount (--private) this directory elsewhere and then do the chroot there, `unshare --mount` then works. I don't know what this means, but I hope this can help find the cause or a workaround (adding a bind mount in the pipeline).

Based on this I found that this does not work:

```
unshare --mount bash -c 'echo hello'
```

But this works:

```
mount --bind --make-private / /mnt 
chroot /mnt unshare --mount bash -c 'echo hello'
umount /mnt
```

Comment: hmm. i don't think you want to use `mount --bind`? I think the command you run will not have access to /proc, for example `ps` will not work. Does your workaround still work if you use `mount --rbind` instead?

Comment: Interesting question although patching proc sys dev and tmp is simple enough. I can try with rbind but the principle is sound either way.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is that `unshare` tries to set the mount propagation flags of the root directory, which can only be done for mount points.  The root directory of the Jenkins chroot environment is not a mount point.

For example:

```
$ unshare -rm mount --make-rprivate /opt
mount: /opt: not mount point or bad option.
```

A complete reproduction:

```
#!/bin/bash
try() {
  mount -t tmpfs t /mnt
  mkdir /mnt/t
  for i in /bin /lib* /sbin /usr /home /proc
  do
    mkdir "/mnt/t$i"
    mount --rbind "$i" "/mnt/t$i"
  done
  chroot /mnt/t unshare -m echo OK
}
export -f try
unshare -rm bash -c try
```

A simple workaround, which makes no mounts outside the mount namespace. It escapes the chroot to set the mount propagation, and assumes the mount command is availble outside the chroot:

```
unshare --propagation unchanged -m sh -c \
'nsenter --mount=/proc/self/ns/mnt mount --make-rslave /; echo Do some mounts'
```

Or convert the chroot into a `pivot_root` environment:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int pivot_root(const char *new_root, const char *put_old){
    return syscall(SYS_pivot_root, new_root, put_old);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (unshare(CLONE_NEWNS))
        error(1, errno, "unshare");

    int root = open("/", O_DIRECTORY | O_PATH | O_CLOEXEC);
    if (root < 0) error(1, errno, "open /");

    int ns = open("/proc/self/ns/mnt", O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);
    if (ns < 0) error(1, errno, "open mount namespace");

    if (setns(ns, CLONE_NEWNS))
        error(1, errno, "setns");

    if (fchdir(root))
        error(1, errno, "fchdir");

    if (mount("/", "/", 0, MS_REC|MS_SLAVE, 0))
        error(1, errno, "mount --make-rslave");

    if (mount(".", "proc", 0, MS_REC|MS_BIND, 0))
        error(1, errno, "mount --rbind");

    if (chdir("proc"))
        error(1, errno, "chdir");

    if (pivot_root(".", "proc"))
        error(1, errno, "pivot_root");

    if (umount2("proc", MNT_DETACH))
        error(1, errno, "umount");

    execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
    error(1, errno, "exec");
}
```

Comment: Thanks +1. That's really useful and may suggest my [workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/554642/20140) was the right corse of action.